# Changing text in specific place (similliar to tabs, pills)

Tags: javascript, html

Noobie here! I am making a game in HTML and I have a lot of tables all over the place and I want to make one so that it actually changes when I press specific button/tab but I really don´t know how to do that. I was thinking about making the whole thing a var that would change but that seems like a bad idea which would stop all the other variables etc. in it working so is there some way to get a specific table or text on the same page to change without influencing any table around it while staying on the same page?

I would like to edit this text -

```
<table id="nabidka">

  <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
    <td>
      <b>
        Buy a factory :
        <button id="BouFac_id" onclick="BouFac()">Price - 1000 Gold</button>
        <p></p>
        <div>Hire Factory workers :
          <button id="BouWork_id" onclick="BouWork()">Price - 100 Gold | wage = 10 Gold/Day</button>
          <p></p>
          Buy a coal mine :
          <button id="BouCMine_id" onclick="BouCMine()">Price - 500 Gold</button>
          <p></p>
          Buy a iron mine :
          <button id="BouIMine_id" onclick="BouIMine()">Price - 700 Gold</button>
          <p></p>
          Buy a smelting furnace :
          <button id="BouSmelFur_id" onclick="BouSmelFur()">Price - 1000 Gold</button>
          <p></p>
          Buy a blast furnace :
          <button id="BouBlast_id" onclick="BouBlast()">Price - 1500 Gold</button>
          <p></p>
          Buy a storage :
          <button id="BouItemStorage_id" onclick="BouItemStorage()">Price - 500 Gold</button>

      </b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it doesen´t matter that I didn´t put div into it cause it is also for some more tabs I dont want to change.

EDIT: I solved it by using hide element on one button which at the same time showed another element. I did the same thing for second button and with sucess!

Comment: yes there that one of main point of javascript to manipulate  the front end if you can past your html code we can tell how to do that

Comment: @kashalo what exact code? Like the one I want to get changed? Should it be with the Java script? And I suppose I should write it as an answer to my posrt right?

Comment: just edit your question and past your html code which you want to get changed, and yes you can do it with javascript, 
again don't past it as answer just edit your question and past it in

Comment: @kashalo done. What now?

Answer (score 1):

you're going to have to store a reference to the cell in the table you want to update into a variable. Add an event listener for the key press with your key that you want to use to update the value then run a function that will change the innerHTML of that specific cell. I feel like this article will give you a great jumping off point:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_tr_cells.asp

Comment: Thank you for this! Even thou I don´t understand much of it I will try to make something of of it. Do you know how these menus I was talking about are called? I think that getting hand on some video would be better then a text form.